# SVD of matrix and SVD of its transpose: U and V exchange places

Tags: matrices, svd, transpose

I have reading the post of [SVD of matrix vs. SVD of its transpose for m < n](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1435968/svd-of-matrix-vs-svd-of-its-transpose-for-m-n)

I am not sure whether  I agree with his conclusions:

So, let $\mathbf{A}(m \times n)$ and $\mathbf{B}(m \times n)$ be two real-valued matrices. Minimizing $\| \mathbf{AQ} - \mathbf{B} \|^2_F$ with $\mathbf{Q}$ being a rotation matrix is achieved by

$$\mathbf{Q} = \mathbf{U} \mathbf{V}^T$$

with the SVD of $\mathbf{A}^T\mathbf{B}$ being

$$\mathbf{A}^T\mathbf{B} = \mathbf{UDV}^T \qquad \text{(case 1)}.$$

Generally, I would assume that we get the same results by using the transpose of $\mathbf{A}^T\mathbf{B}$, i.e.

$$\mathbf{B}^T\mathbf{A} = \mathbf{UDV}^T \qquad \text{(case 2)}$$

and calculating

$$\mathbf{Q} = \mathbf{V} \mathbf{U}^T$$

%%%%%%%%%%%

However, according to my understanding when you take the transpose of a matrix, the  $\mathbf{U}$ and $\mathbf{V}$ swap places, then the SVD looks like

$$\mathbf{B}^T\mathbf{A} = \mathbf{VDU}^T \qquad \text{(case 2)}$$

Is this correct?

Comment: I think that you've misunderstood what the commenter is trying to say. The $U$ and $V$ from $B^TA = UDV^T$ are not supposed to be the same $U$ and $V$ as are obtained from the earlier equation $A^TB = UDV^T$.

Comment: Hello Ben, that is where my confusion comes from. So, you agree that what the commuter presented is correct?  I will need to rethink about that. Thanks a lot